# Laravel reassign query variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I don't understand why sometimes I can make a code like this:

```
$query = Model::where('...');
if (isset($onlyVIP))
    $query->where('VIP', true);
$query->get();
```

And other times I need to re-assign the var like this:

```
$query = Model::where('...');
if (isset($onlyVIP))
    $query = $query->where('VIP', true);
$query = $query->get();
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work. If you directly return data for ajax or something then first approach is OK. Just return. Like-

```
$query = Model::where('...');
if (isset($onlyVIP))
    $query->where('VIP', true);

return $query->get();
```

Now if you like to work with your data, then you need something to hold your object. That's the second approach.

Comment: Thanks, my question was more focused on if it was possible to save the result of the query inside $query with the first approach, but now I see I can't.